# How many document is couchdb can contain?

Tags: couchdb

I'm trying to find any limitation for CouchDB. I need to know how much documents that Couch can contain. could their _id be used up ?. or another limitation posed by CouchDB since i rely on couchDB for many project lately.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of stored documents in CouchDB is only limited by available disk space for database files. You can limit maximum document size (in bytes) with `couchdb/max_document_size` option, but you cannot set any limits for document's count within single database.

Comment: thanks, do you know any other limitations posed by couch db ? or an article about it somewhere ?